# Max Length on text field + automatic dashes in between letters?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I would like to have a text field dedicate to a Serial Number that contains up to 12 digits, the digits normally come separated by 2. example: 12-34-56-78-90-12. Is it possible to make them automatically add the dash and only allow 12 numbers/letters to be entered?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Column settings for the text field where you can specify the maximum characters.

[image]

Or you can specify it in the column validation settings where you can set the formula and custom message.

=IF(LEN(Your column name)<12,TRUE,FALSE)

[image]

But there's no OOTB way to automatically add dash.